# PostgreSQL Grouping error

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel

I got this error when i was executing this query on PostgreSQL:

```
SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column "posts.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT posts.id, posts.* FROM "posts" GROUP BY "pos..
```

and this is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.id, posts.* 
FROM "posts" 
GROUP BY "posts"."id" 
ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

although it did worked when I was executing it with mysql, so how can i fix this?

Comment: Why do you use `distinct` **and** droup by. This does not make any sense. And why do you select the id column twice? (Once explicitely and once due to the `*`)

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Newer versions of PostgreSQL would generally execute this fine if `posts.id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`. That said, this is a completely nonsensical query.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. If "id" is primary, you wouldn't need to use `GROUP` or use `DISTINCT` (which, as pointed out, are redundant here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that in PostgreSQL you need to add all the columns you want to have in your select to your group by.

so your statement should be like

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY column1, column2...
```

Comment: This is not specific to Postgres, this is required by the SQL standard. MySQL's sloppy implementation of this is more like a bug than a feature. And MySQL should be configured to use `strict_group_by` to avoid this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL with `ANSI` and `STRICT` using InnoDB tables is almost sane. Pity it doesn't ship like that by default.

Comment: @CraigRinger: `ansi` does not include ` ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, you need to enable that seperately.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you know of a good list of "Make MySQL sane" settings? I've been wondering for a while about something to point people to, esp. when they're considering a MySQL->Pg migration where fixing up the worst MySQL-isms first would help.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I usually recommend `ANSI, NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES, STRICT_ALL_TABLES, NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO, NO_ZERO_DATE, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, PIPES_AS_CONCAT, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`

Comment: BTW, ArchiFloyd, your statement isn't strictly true: If the primary key is included the RDBMS is allowed to assume that all other cols are implicitly included. Newer Pg versions do exactly this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/57770/2

Comment: I didn't know that, our database course teacher just told us that in standard SQL you need to do this, but then again, the error he got, seems like this is the problem, good to know that postgreSQL can use the primary key to do this, thanks for the comment :)

Comment: so you can run a `select *` but then have to do `group by each,single,column,this,will,never,end,and,is,so,tedious,each,timesometing,changes,Ihaveto,add,anew,entry` ????

Comment: I agree with MySQL autoing this process because it's just absurdly stupid to have to specify all columns again in the group by clause, it makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  "posts"."id" ORDER BY   "posts"."id") No, posts.*
 FROM "posts"  ) AS T1 WHERE T1.NO = 1
 ORDER BY "id" DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```