# Laravel Removing Pivot data in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, tags, pivot-table

Not sure if I set this up correctly. In Laravel I'm creating two models with a many-to-may relationship

The models are `Item` and `Tags`. Each one contains a `belongsTo` to the other.

When I run a query like so:

```
Item::with('tags')->get();
```

It returns the collection of `items`, with each item containing a `tags` collection. However the each tag in the collection also contains `pivot` data which I don't need. Here it is in json format:

```
[{
    "id":"49",
    "slug":"test",
    "order":"0","tags":[
        {"id":"3","name":"Blah","pivot":{"item_id":"49","tag_id":"3"}},
        {"id":"13","name":"Moo","pivot":{"item_id":"49","tag_id":"13"}}
    ]
}]
```

Is there anyway to prevent this data from getting at

Comment: This is an obvious duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887530/laravel-4-1-remove-pivot-attributes-from-response - Please remove the bounty so we can close it as duplicate.

Comment: This seems to only work when I do a `->toArray()` or `->toJson()` but if i just print out `$item->tags` I still see the pivot data in the object. Seems like it's doing unnecessary querying as I'm not trying to access any data from the pivot table. Still would like an answer.

Comment: For instance if I were to write the query directly through the pivot: `SELECT t.* FROM tags AS t JOIN city_tag AS ct WHERE ct.item_id = 111;`

Comment: No, that's the way the API is supposed to work. It does not waste that many more resources (except bandwidth for transmitting them from the DB maybe) by supplying the pivot data too. And I think you do understand that there's no other way of implementing a many-to-many relationship other than a _pivot table_. `$hidden` is an API _feature_ (of Eloquent) and as such is only available if you use _the API_ (`toArray`, `toJson`). A PHP dump of the objects will obviously present all the information within. There is no other _answer_ here.

Comment: The query generated by Eloquent would be close to this one: `SELECT t.*, ct.* FROM tags AS t JOIN city_tag AS ct WHERE ct.item_id = 111;` - no real performance penalty here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have asked and you shall receive your answer. But first a few words to sum up the comment section. I personally don't know why you would want / need to do this. I understand if you want to [hide it from the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887530/laravel-4-1-remove-pivot-attributes-from-response) but not selecting it from the DB really has no real benefit. Sure, less data will be transferred and the DB server has a tiny tiny bit less work to do, but you won't notice that in any way.

However it is possible. It's not very pretty though, since you have to override the `belongsToMany` class.

First, the new relation class:

```
class BelongsToManyPivotless extends BelongsToMany {
    /**
     * Hydrate the pivot table relationship on the models.
     *
     * @param  array  $models
     * @return void
     */
    protected function hydratePivotRelation(array $models)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    /**
     * Get the pivot columns for the relation.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getAliasedPivotColumns()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

As you can see this class is overriding two methods. `hydratePivotRelation` would normally create the pivot model and fill it with data. `getAliasedPivotColumns` would return an array of all columns to select from the pivot table.

Now we need to get this integrated into our model. I suggest you use a `BaseModel` class for this but it also works in the model directly.

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public function belongsToManyPivotless($related, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null){
        if (is_null($relation))
        {
            $relation = $this->getBelongsToManyCaller();
        }

        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $instance = new $related;

        $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();

        if (is_null($table))
        {
            $table = $this->joiningTable($related);
        }

        $query = $instance->newQuery();

        return new BelongsToManyPivotless($query, $this, $table, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
    }
}
```

I edited the comments out for brevity but otherwise the method is just like `belongsToMany` from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. Of course except the relation class that gets created. Here we use our own `BelongsToManyPivotless`.

And finally, this is how you use it:

```
class Item extends BaseModel {
    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToManyPivotless('Tag');
    }
}
```

Comment: but why all that ? you wan just this in your model :                                protected $hidden = ['pivot'];

Comment: I can give a case where it is needed : with Postgresql if the select contains a grouping operation (SUM, COUNT), it is required that all columns have a grouping operation or appear in the GROUP BY. Here the extra pivot columns create a "grouping error", see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012818/postgresql-grouping-error

Comment: That's amazing, @Amine_Dev! I was looking for this answer... So easy!

Comment: Another use case are `unions` where you can get `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

Answer (score 19):

you can just add the name of the field in the hidden part in your model like this:

```
protected $hidden = ['pivot'];
```

that's it , it works fine with me.

Comment: this work on entire model, but how can I do for just one method?

thnaks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove pivot data then you can use as `protected $hidden = ['pivot'];` @Amine_Dev suggested, so i have used it but it was not working for me,

but the problem really was that i was using it in wrong model so i want to give more detail in it that where to use it, so you guys don't struggle with the problem which i have struggled.

So if you are fetching the data as :

```
Item::with('tags')->get();
```

then you have to assign pivot to hidden array like below

**But keep in mind that you have to define it in `Tag` model not in `Item` model**

```
class Tag extends Model {

   protected $hidden = ['pivot'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two possible ways to do this

**1. using makeHidden method on resulting model**

```
$items = Item::with('tags')->get();
return $items->makeHidden(['pivot_col1', 'pivot_col2']...)
```

**2. using array_column function of PHP**

```
$items = Item::with('tags')->get()->toArray();

 return array_column($items, 'tags');
```

Comment: Please note that **makeHidden()** is a **Collection** method, it won't work on **Model.** It's a method of eloquent, not query builder.